# Получение значения из компонента JSF

Tags: java, веб-программирование, jsf, primefaces

Как передать значение из одного компонента в другой?

```
<p:ajax event="view" update="URL" listener="#{x.lis}" oncomplete="window.open('??URL.value??')" />
<h:inputHidden id="URL" value="#{x.value}" />
```

Hidden содержит нужный мне URL, как передать его значение в oncomplete?

Comment: А что, просто `oncomplete="window.open('#{x.value}')"` - не работает? Для этого требуется, чтобы компонент, в котором находится `p:ajax`, тоже обновлялся, т.е., его надо добавить в `update`. А вообще, передача данных через `inputHidden` в современном JSF может быть оправдана в основном в случаях, если страница взаимодействует со сторонним JavaScript-ом, результаты работы которого надо передать на сервер. Похоже на то, что это не ваш случай (подозреваю, что #{x.lis} меняет URL, а не JavaScript). Лучше задайте новый вопрос и опишите в нём вашу задачу, наверняка найдётся более элегантное решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('absolute_id_part:URL').value
```

где absolute_id_part - клиентский id контейнера inputHidden